# How to troubleshoot no such column error sqldf in r

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm getting an error `(no such column: cs7.Start)` while executing a Where clause using sqldf in r. I have looked at the other historical post and tested few things (single quote, underscore) but of no luck. Any help appreciated.

```
dat <- structure(list(TIMESTAMP = c("2021-06-18 11:36:00", "2021-06-18 11:38:00", 
"2021-06-18 11:40:00", "2021-06-18 11:42:00", "2021-06-18 11:44:00", 
"2021-06-18 11:46:00"), VWC_CS7 = c(0.046, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 
0.044, 0.045), row_id = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

cs7 <- structure(list(Serial_Number = 1:6, Start = c(101L, 634L, 797L, 
1434L, 2089L, 2490L), End = c(634L, 797L, 1434L, 2089L, 2490L, 
4204L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

library(sqldf)
new_df <- sqldf("select * from dat Where dat.row_id = cs7.Start and dat.row_id=cs7.End")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a inner join. To make it work you need to explicitly join the two tables or to include both tables in the `select` statement's `from` clause.

```r
dat <- structure(list(TIMESTAMP = c("2021-06-18 11:36:00", "2021-06-18 11:38:00", 
                                    "2021-06-18 11:40:00", "2021-06-18 11:42:00", 
                                    "2021-06-18 11:44:00", "2021-06-18 11:46:00"), 
                      VWC_CS7 = c(0.046, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.045), 
                      row_id = 1:6), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

cs7 <- structure(list(Serial_Number = 1:6, 
                      Start = c(101L, 634L, 797L, 1434L, 2089L, 2490L), 
                      End = c(634L, 797L, 1434L, 2089L, 2490L, 4204L)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

library(sqldf)
#> Loading required package: gsubfn
#> Loading required package: proto
#> Loading required package: RSQLite

sql <- 
"select dat.TIMESTAMP, dat.VWC_CS7, dat.row_id 
  from dat
  inner join cs7
  on dat.row_id = cs7.Start and
     dat.row_id = cs7.End"

new_df <- sqldf(sql)
new_df
#> [1] TIMESTAMP VWC_CS7   row_id   
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

sql2 <- 
  "select dat.TIMESTAMP, dat.VWC_CS7, dat.row_id 
  from dat, cs7
  where dat.row_id = cs7.Start and
        dat.row_id = cs7.End"

new_df2 <- sqldf(sql2)
new_df2
#> [1] TIMESTAMP VWC_CS7   row_id   
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>